# can not able to delete the images of products

Tags: magento-1.9, image, delete

I want to delete the uploaded images. what i tried is

I went  to backend and than go to `catalog > Manage products`, i opened single product and went to `Images` section. i checked on checkbox below `Remove` as in below image and i saved the product. but still those images are not deleting.

[image]

Comment: In this particular case the desire of the author is to delete an image. He/she goes to catalog/manage products, selects a product, then selects the image he/she wants to delete by checking "remove". Then he/she saves this action. But, the image is still there. I have the same problem. Why is the image still there after being checked "remove" and this action being saved?

Answer (score 10):

I had a the described issue two weeks ago. The image was not removed from the products `Images` tab, because the setting from the default scope was overwritten on store view level.

So I would suggest checking the products image configuration on the lower configuration scopes (website, store view) to see if the `Use Default` checkbox was deactivated somewhere. After rectifying that, you should be able to delete the image as described in your question.